# Grouping with Dynamic testng

Tags: testng

i am dynamically creating my testNG xml and now we have introduced concept of grouping for our testcases. I tried adding groups to my testNG but somehow it is not working. Tried it at Suite level as well as test level but still couldn't figure out exact issue. Below is example of test level grouping

**Below is my code:**

```java
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

    for (BrowserEnvironment environment : browserEnvironments)
    {
        XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
        suite.setName(environment.getBrowser() + "-" + environment.getVersion() + "-" + suiteName);
        suite.setParallel(XmlSuite.PARALLEL_METHODS);
        suite.setThreadCount(threadCount);

        for (String className : includeMethodsMap.keySet())
        {
            XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
            List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
            List<XmlInclude> methodNames = includeMethodsMap.get(className);
            XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(Class.forName(className));
            xmlClass.setIncludedMethods(methodNames);
            xmlClasses.add(xmlClass);
            test.setName(xmlClass.getName().substring(1 + xmlClass.getName().lastIndexOf(".")));
            test.setXmlClasses(xmlClasses);
            test.addIncludedGroup(SettingMapConstants.DefaultSet);
        }
        suites.add(suite);
    }

    testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);
```

**Generated TestNG.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="10" name="Firefox-43.0-_TestSuite" parallel="methods">
  <test name="ExecutionSettings">
    <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="DefaultSet"/>
      </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.zycus.automation.eproc.testcase.settingMap.ExecutionSettings">
        <methods>
          <include name="sudoDefaultSet"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working ? The generated xml does have the group information that you are looking for. What is missing ?

Comment: i have a class file where i have one BeforeGroup annotation and one Test annotation. My group name is 'DefaultSet'. 
Code for the same is:
`@BeforeGroups(groups = SettingMapConstants.DefaultSet)
public void beforeGroupDefaultSet() throws Exception
{  
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider", groups = SettingMapConstants.DefaultSet, priority=0)
public void sudoDefaultSet(TestCase testCase) throws Exception
{
}`

somehow generated xml is not able to identify beforeGroup present in this class.

Comment: Please edit your question and include appropriate details so that someone can help take a look. Your xml shows only one class that is being included. So the group filtering will be effective only on that class.